# Why is this XQuery return an empty sequence while I'm expecting 5?

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8

I'm confused with the below query, I expect the result should be **5** but it returns an **empty sequence**.

[image]

```
let $num := 5
let $num1 := ()
let $add := $num + $num1
return $add
```

Comment: It might make more sense if you think of the empty sequence as being roughly the equivalent of NULL in SQL. In SQL, most operations deliver NULL if one of the operands is NULL; the same is true (treating () as NULL) in XQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how close Marklogic XQuery is to the W3C XQuery standard but in that standard the rules for arithmetic expressions https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xquery-20101214/#id-arithmetic clearly say

> The first step in evaluating an arithmetic expression is to evaluate
> its operands. The order in which the operands are evaluated is
> implementation-dependent.
>
> Each operand is evaluated by applying the following steps, in order:
>
> Atomization is applied to the operand. The result of this operation is
> called the atomized operand.
>
> If the atomized operand is an empty sequence, the result of the
> arithmetic expression is an empty sequence

So the empty sequence is the defined result as one operand is the empty sequence.

Perhaps the [`sum()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-sum) function, `let $add := sum(($num, $num1))`, is more what you are looking for.

Comment: You could avoid some of the confusion and instead force an error if you typed your variables, or applied some checks to avoid `()` and substitute `0` instead. You could `let $num1 as xs:numeric` or `xs:integer`, or whatever numeric type you are expecting. You could also use functions such as `max()` to substitute `0` when the variable happen to be empty sequence: `let $add := max(($num, 0)) + max(($num1,0))`

Comment: @MadsHansen, I think in the end `let $add := sum($num, $num1)` might be simpler and "just do" what the poster expects from the `+` operator.

Comment: Yes, of course! Much better